# Why is $c_0 =\overline{span\{e_n:n\ge1\}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I came across this fact in my notes that in given without proof, and I am having trouble proving it.

$c_0 = \overline{span\{e_n:n\ge1\}}$? where $e_n$ is the sequence with a $1$ in the n-th component and $0$ elsewhere and $c_0$ is the set of infinitesimal sequences with the sup norm

**My try:**

I need to prove that $\forall \varepsilon> 0 \forall x \in c_0\exists y \in span\{e_n:n\ge1\}$ such that $sup_{k  \ge 1}|x_k-y_k|<\epsilon$

So $y$ must be of the form $y=\sum_{n=1}^{N} y_ne_n$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y_n \in \mathbb{C}$ .

Furthermore by definition of limit, since $x \in c_0$, we have that $\forall \varepsilon> 0  \exists K(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall k \ge K(\varepsilon)$, $|x_k|\le \varepsilon$

This is as far as I got, how do I finish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ the span of the $e_n$. It is clear that $E \subset c_0$ and $c_0$ is closed hence $\overline{E} \subset c_0$.

Suppose $x \in c_0$, then $x(n) \to 0$, let $x_k$ be equal to $x$ for the first $k$ components and zero afterwards. Then we see that $\|x-x_k\| \to 0$. Since $x_k \in E$, we see that $x \in \overline{E}$.

Comment: How do we know $c_0$  is closed? How do I prove rigorously that $sup_{n \ge k+1}|x(n)| \to 0$, for$ k\to \infty$?

Comment: For the first, look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2462750/27978.

Comment: For the second, you can't, it is not true and I do not understand the relevance.

Comment: Do we have to consider  $c_0 $ closed with respect to $l^\infty$? Can't we consider it closed as a subspace of itself?

Comment: To prove this  $\|x-x_k\| \to 0$ I get to the expresion in my first comment, so it mush be correct, right? Intuitively I am taking the sup over a smaller set when n grows, so I wanted to formalize it

Comment: If you consider $c_0$ as the space within which you are taking the closure, then you do not need to show that it is closed as the whole space. (That is not the same as saying it is closed in $l_\infty$, of course.) To prove $\|x-x_k\| \to 0$ you just need to note that $x(n) \to 0$ and since $x_k(n) = 0$ for $n >k$, the result follows.

Comment: Note, for example, that the set $A=\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is closed within $\mathbb{Q}$, but generally unless specified otherwise, one would not refer to $A$ as being closed without further elaboration. Since $c_0$ is complete this is not an issue here.

Comment: does the same sequence $x_k$ works  to prove $ l^1=\overline{span\{e_n:n\ge1\}}$ ?

Comment: If you mean the closure with the $1$-norm, then yes.